# number of catkin directory in ROS

Tags: ros

I am new to ROS.
As introduced in the tutorial, a catkin workspace is required when working with ROS.
The directory given by the tutorial is: ~/catkin_ws/

In the workspace, the tutorial build a package called *beginner_tutorials*.

Question is that if **a** catkin workspace is only for **a** project(system?) which based on several packages. If I have another project which based on different packages, shall I use the same catkin workspace (i.e. only one catkin workspace per computer/user)? OR shall I create a new catkin workspace (say ~/projectXX/catkin_ws/).

Thanks.

Comment: I personaly use one catkin workspace for all my projects. This works fine for me. I would say, one catkin workspace is for a system not for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say both is fine, it depends on what is more fitting for you.

Putting everything in one workspace is the most simple and convenient way and there is nothing wrong with that.

On the other hand, if you are working on different projects that are independent from each other, separate workspaces give you more structure (and the possibility to have packages with the same name in the separate projects).

In case you use, like me, QtCreator as IDE, there is even a reason to have multiple workspaces for the same project (using `setup.bash --extend`).
I use one workspace for the packages I am working on, and another for all the packages I need as dependency but which I do not edit.
The reason is that with QtCreator you usually open the whole workspace as a CMake project and thus get all packages in that workspace listed in the projects view.
By using separate workspaces I see only the packages I am interested in and additionally compile time is reduced as only the packages in this workspace are checked for changes.

Comment: Just a comment about using QtCreator to open CMakeLists.txt: you can open the CMakeLists under the src/package folder rather than the one under src. You then select sub build folder, then you won't open the all the projects in QtCreator.

Comment: This does not really work for me. Maybe I miss some option here but I have not yet figured out, how to make QtCreator use the right build _and_ devel folder without having to set the required cmake parameter every time by hand (see [related question on ros answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/67244/qtcreator-with-catkin/))

Comment: Yes I did run catkin_make once before open the CMakeLists.txt in the src/package using QtCreator. I guess in this way, as the post said, the setting of catkin is inherited by the QtCreator.

Comment: For me, this works only for the "main" CMakeLists.txt of the workspace. If I open the CMakeLists.txt of a single package it gets messed up as soon as I rerun cmake from inside QtCreator (binaries are then located in ws/build/package_name/devel instead of ws/devel).